# Python - TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt

def ceil_dt(dt, delta):
    return dt + (dt.min - dt) % delta

NextInterval5m = ceil_dt(now, timedelta(minutes=5))

unixtime5m = dt.fromtimestamp(NextInterval5m)
```

The problem is that i keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)
```

Can someone help me out on this? I don't understand to what i am supposed to convert `NextInterval5m` in order to make it work. I'm trying to convert `NextInterval5m` to an Unix timestamp

Comment: What is `ceil_dt`?

Comment: My bad, it's a function that i forgot to include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to convert it into a unix timestamp by using `.timestamp()` on a `datetime.datetime` object. However, this function is exclusive to Python 3. If you need something for python 2, you can use `.total_seconds()` which requires a `datetime.time_delta` object instead.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3.3+, use `.timestamp()`

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

def ceil_dt(dt, delta):
    return dt + (dt.min - dt) % delta

now = dt.now()
NextInterval5m = ceil_dt(now, timedelta(minutes=5))
unixtime5m = NextInterval5m.timestamp()
print(unixtime5m)
```

Output:

```
1596926400.0
```

OR

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

def ceil_dt(dt, delta):
    return dt + (dt.min - dt) % delta

now = dt.now()
NextInterval5m = ceil_dt(now, timedelta(minutes=5))
unixtime5m = NextInterval5m.timestamp()

print((NextInterval5m - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
```